# Orbeon XForms - How to replace part of an instance with values from a SOAP response

Tags: xml, xpath, orbeon, xforms

I have an instance in my model, which contains an empty section which I need to replace with the response of a SOAP web service call.

```
<xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  <form>
     <SomeElement />
     <SoapResponse />
     <AnotherElement />
  </form>
</xf:instance >
```

I call a web service via a trigger, and I want the reponse to replace the "SoapResponse" element in my instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that you've written your own `xf:submission`, and that the result of the service call goes to some other instance, say `soap-response`. Assuming this is the case, you can, on `xforms-submit-done`, run an `xf:insert` to copy the content of the response from the `soap-response` instance to the `<SoapResponse />` element in the `fr-form-instance` instance.